# MVC3 field not validating on production server

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, poco

I'm using EF + MVC3 with .net 4, I've got an upload field in my form, and on my dev server, it works perfectly as expected, but when I move it up to my production server, whenver the form is posted I get the `The value '' is invalid.` validation error, even when I am submitting an image up (I've checked in FireBug, and the field is populated).

Looking online, whenever this crops up, it seems to be down to the setter on the EF model being non-public. But this can't be the case, as this property on the model doesn't map to any field in the database (I don't use the EF Poco's directly, I've crafted models around them).

I'm thinking it's probably an IIS discrepancy as my dev server is running IIS7 .net4, where as the production one is running IIS6 .net4.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could be happening?

**Model:**

```
public class AddBookModel {
    public AddBookModel () { }
    public AddBookModel(Book book) {
        Title = book.Title;
        Description = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(book.Description);
        CoverExtension = book.CoverExtension;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="This field cannot be blank")]
    [DataType(DataType.Html)]
    [Display(Name="Description:")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="This field cannot be blank")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name="Title:")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private string _CoverExtension = String.Empty;
    public string CoverExtension {
        get { return _CoverExtension; }
        private set { if (value != null) { _CoverExtension = value; } }
    }

    public virtual string CoverPath { get { return String.Empty; } }

    private HttpPostedFileBase _Image;
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image {
        get { return _Image; }
        set { _Image = value; CoverExtension = value.GetFileExtension(); }
    }
    public ResultStatuses ActionStatus { get; set; }
}
```

**View (Relevant bit):**

```
    <div class="field @if (ViewData.ModelState["Image"] != null && ViewData.ModelState["Image"].Errors.Count > 0) { <text>field-error</text>}">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Image)
        @Html.Upload("Image")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Image, null, new { @class="error-hint" })
    </div>
```

**Update**

I've now checked the code at my workplace, which is running the same IIS version as the production server (I believe), and it works fine, aside from writing permissions to the filesystem where I'm trying to upload the file, but that's not going to be related to the validation error is it?

**Html Upload Helper:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString Upload(this HtmlHelper helper, string name) {
            string result = string.Format("<input type=\"file\" id=\"{0}\" name=\"{0}\" />", name);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result);
        }
```

Comment: Definitely have no idea, especially without code.  64/32 bit you'd get an error much earlier.

Comment: Not a clue without seeing your code.

Comment: You have no validation rules on your image, it shouldn't be invalid ever.  Also, you're using some 3rd party Html Helper for the Upload helper, so without knowing what that is...

Comment: @Mystere Man
Exactly, which is why I'm a little confused as to why it gives a validation error. I'll put the code for the helper up, but it's literally a 1-line thing which renders an input

Comment: Something else is going on.  MVC can only validate when there is an attribute on the field.  It's simply not possible for it to be failing validation on a field without any kind of attribute on it.

Comment: Could you post your entire view? You have included all the required fields in your view - i.e. title and description?

Comment: Figured out what the issue was, it was the setter for the image, where I'm assinging a value to the CoverExtension property, the method doing that was failing, and so setting null to the value (though it should have been throwing an exception, rather than silently failing which is why I didn't pick up on it)

Answer (score 0):

IIS 6 and IIS 7 have different file upload limits. According to [this](http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/File_Upload_limits.asp), the default upload size limit on IIS6 is a meagre 200kb, while on IIS 7 it's 30mb according to [this](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits). That said, from the second link, one would expect a different error if this is your actual problem (I can't test this right now).